# Is there any way to Read/Write object to .csv

Tags: c#, .net, csv

I am looking for some thing like .Net utility which allows you to export data/object to .csv and similarly read that data. Same like we have a concept of xmlSerialization.

Thanx

Comment: CSV is a very limited format in that it is rigidly 2-dimensional; this would work for an homogeneous list of shallow objects, but won't work if there are any association properties etc

Comment: What kind of look do you want for your output, BreakHead? I mean, if you have an object with properties and those probperties are objects with properties, what should that look like in your CSV?

Comment: @Matt, that's why I posted this question, because I dnt have to worry about pattern they will stored in .csv, same as in xmlserialization the xml we get manage all object having property as object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be quicker and easier to write your own parser for this purpose. All you need to do is create a text file and append it with all the parameters of your object separated by a delimiter (";").

When you are reading it back in you will know the order of the parameters that are coming in and how they are separated so you can create a new object and convert the strings into their appropriate types and apply these values to your new object.

Comment: Not a problem, hope it goes well!

Comment: Is there as specific reason you need csv format why not serialize the object instead which save the memory state of the object

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [SimpleCSV](http://simplecsv.codeplex.com/releases/view/52921)? (codeplex project)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own serializer/parser using the `String.Join` and `String.Split` methods.